# Create or Update cookie array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I want to create if the value is 0 and update if the value is 1.

So I wrote this one,

```
var juiceCart = [{
    'name': val,
    'count': unTouch
}];
if (value == 0) {
    console.log('create cookie');
    $.cookie("juiceCart", JSON.stringify(juiceCart));
    doDummyCall();
} else {
    console.log('update cookie');
    $.cookie("juiceCart", JSON.stringify(juiceCart));
    doDummyCall();
}
```

Inside the `doDummyCall()`

I am just doing a ajax call to update the headers and

```
var cookieJuiceCart = $.parseJSON($.cookie("juiceCart"));
$.each(cookieJuiceCart, function (index, value) {
    console.log('Id : ' + value.name);
    console.log('Value : ' + value.count);
});
```

and then printing the cookie in each function to know all the items present in it.

If i add the first item, it is printing

Id : 1
Value : 1

Then, if i add the Second item it is printing

Id : 2
Value : 1

But what i expect is

Id : 1
Value : 1
Id : 2
Value : 1

I know that the old value is replaced because i am not pushing the value in it.

So, I did

```
juiceCart.push({'name': val, 'count': unTouch});
```

But it is just replacing the old value with new one.

How can i check the existence of old value inside the array and create or update according to it.

Comment: Try Jquery cookie plugin

Comment: @MaximColesnic I am using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie only

Comment: @Epodax Removed php tag

Comment: Is it just me or are you doing the exact same thing on create and on update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem seems to me is your array:

```
var juiceCart = [{
    'name': val,
    'count': unTouch
}];
```

which is using vars to update same object instead of pushing new object.

You can do this:

```
var juiceCart = $.parseJSON($.cookie("juiceCart")) || []; // create a blank array taken from @apokryfos's answer.
juiceCart.push({'name': val, 'count': unTouch}); // <---now push it here.
```

This way you are able to push new object each time you call it.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to pushing it like you said, but it was just replacing the entire content only.. :(

Comment: @SulthanA updated seems like this is the issue. You need to push new object each time , instead of updating it.

Comment: i tried to do var juiceCart = []; before pushing .. but still the same.. it is replacing the old one..

Comment: When i try to do this `var juiceCart = $.parseJSON($.cookie("juiceCart"));
                juiceCart.push({'name': val, 'count': unTouch});` it is showing having all the old values like 1:1, 1:2 , 2:1, 2:2

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from the question. It's a bit poorly explained so I may not have understood what you need to do.

```
var juiceCart = $.parseJSON($.cookie("juiceCart")) || [];
var newItem = true;
juiceCart.each(function (i, v) { 
    if (v.name == val) { v.count++; newItem = false; }
});
if (newItem) {
    juiceCart.push({'name': val, 'count': unTouch});
}
$.cookie("juiceCart", JSON.stringify(juiceCart));
doDummyCall();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in your answer, can u pls explain ?

Comment: First of all, you get the current `juiceCart` from the cookie, or create a new array if it's not set. Then you check if `val` exists in the `juiceCart`. This is done via the `newItem` boolean. If it does exist, you increment the `count` of the corresponding entry. If it doesn't exist you push `{'name': val, 'count': unTouch}` in `juiceCart` then you replace the cookie value with the updated array and run `doDummyCall()` as before.